# Recovering data from "luks + ext4" formatted usb stick

Tags: usb, encryption, luks

i've a usb stick formatted with built-in ubuntu 16.04 options(just disks tool, nothing extra installed to encryption e.g cryptsetup etc) but i've lost my passphrase/password. Is there any way to recover data in this usb?

Another but related Question/recommendation : Is there any better tool to store data safe in a usb other than disks tool(with luks+ext4 formatting) or this one good enough?

Comment: A backdoor for people who have lost the passphrase/password would defeat the purpose of encryption. So I am sorry. It is a good idea to keep an unencrypted backup of the data that you cannot afford to lose, and to keep that backup in a safe place.

Comment: even if i'm on the computer that formatted the usb stick?
edit: yep, i've search some and there is no difference even if you are on the same computer. There is no backdoor :(

Comment: That's right. Maybe after a good night's sleep, you will remember the password/passphrase :-)

Comment: thanks for your answer, if you post it as answer including 2. question, i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A backdoor for people who have lost the passphrase/password would defeat the purpose of encryption. So I am sorry.

It is a good idea to keep an unencrypted backup of the data that you cannot afford to lose, and to keep that backup in a safe place.

Maybe after a good night's sleep, you will remember the password/passphrase :-)